# iphone message center - how to get the message arrival time

Tags: objective-c, xcode4

When I open the message center (by sliding it down from the top) I can see that each message is associated with "how long ago it arrived". How to get that info?
I also have checked out and it seems that when I create a local notification with the repeatInterval the fireDate remains the same as in the original for all repetitions. 
Thus I don't know how to distinguish between the dates of each local notification since the popups are non-modal. Any suggestions? 
Thanks. 
Regards, Victor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe the time of arrival is available to you. You can send additional details with the notification's JSON though with a timestamp that you then read in your applicationDidLaunch:(NSNotification *) method.

Comment: Hello Jeremy and thanks for the clarification. I am dealing here with the local notifications - can you please explain about JSON usage there? Thanks. Victor